# how to persist data throughout all pages in the application?

Tags: firebase

Hi I am developing a cross platform application. I have a register page where I get the user details like user email and password and other details. I save all data under that particular user. I create a child with the unique email id given by the user and all remaining details must be stored under that user[image]
Now I need the above product data and service data stored inside the first user. My path must always be the user who is logged in the application. Should I take that data to all  pages. How to do it Can someone please help me?
Here is code how I create the above structure inside my database.

```
$(".subscribe1").click(function(){
    var t1 = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var t2 = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var t3 = document.getElementById("confirmpassword").value;
    var companyname = document.getElementById("companyname").value;
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
        var pincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
        var sname = document.getElementById("sname").value;
        var sid = document.getElementById("sid").value;
        var saddr = document.getElementById("saddr").value;
        var scity = document.getElementById("scity").value;
        var spincode = document.getElementById("spincode").value;
        var scountry = document.getElementById("scountry").value;
        var s;
        s = (t1.replace('.', ','));
console.log(s);
        var ref = new Firebase("https://sampleapp.firebaseio.com/");
        var account = ref.child(s+"/master_account");
        account.push({"email": t1 , "password": t2});
        var cmp = ref.child(s+"/company_details");
        cmp.push({"email": t1, "company_name": companyname , "address": address, "city": city, "pincode": pincode, "country": country});
       var store = ref.child(s+"/store_location");
        store.push({"email": t1, "store_name": sname , "store_id" :sid , "address": saddr, "city": scity, "pincode": spincode, "country": scountry});
});
```

Comment: Do you want the data or the particular user to be used across all pages of your app? is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes I need that data so that I can give that path to save product,service @BabajideFowotade

Answer (score 0):

To be clear on your point, you want a logged in user's data to be available across your app.

Here are possible measures you could take to achieving that.

- Once a user is logged in.

  - Save the basic data to localstorage, cache or sessionstore (data such as first_name, last_name, email).
  - Then for other pages, you can then query firebase to load other data you need for that page.

`ref.child(email).child('master_account').once('value', () => {});`

Once you get that data, you could save it somewhere in a variable object if you only want to use it for that page alone or cache or localstorage or session-store if you want to use it across other pages.

If a user then logs out, you'd clear the cache,local-storage or session-store whichever you choose to save the data in. And also you'd do a check to see if a user's detail still exists in any of those otherwise you'd log them out.

-I hope this helps.